# Drupal 7 Apache solr search module

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

We have tried to remove the search result for the particular node in Drupal 7. We can't make that change. Is it possible to remove the Apache solr search result for the particular node?. Can any one help us?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it from search results? I think adding a filter would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform this by adding a filter to the query in hook_apachesolr_query_alter() :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_apachesolr_query_alter().
 * 
 * @param DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query
 * @see apachesolr.interface.inc
 */
function yourmodule_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  $nid = 1234;
  $exclude = TRUE;
  $filter = apachesolr_site_hash() . '/node/' . $nid;
  $query->addFilter('id', $filter, $exclude);
}
```

Comment: Yes, there was a typo! fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In search result view of SOLR (which is responsible for displaying the search result), you can add filter criteria with NID of the particular node, and then negate the condition. Now the search result will include all the nodes except the particular node whose NID is provided.

This is the quickest solution considering that you have a lots of content in your site.